# Pass route to controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass a route to a controller action. For example, if I have a controller action `/Files/Index`, I want to pass a route to the controller, like `/Files/some/path/here` such that my `Index` action picks up `/some/path/here`. Is this possible?

```
public class FilesController : Controller
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Index(string route)
    {
        // `route` should contain everything 
        // after the controller action
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Specify a custom route.

## MVC4

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Files",
    url: "Files/Index/{*route}"
);
```

## MVC5

```
[Route("Files/Index/{*route}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Index(string route)
{
    // `route` should contain everything 
    // after the controller action
}
```

Comment: It shows "404 - File or directory not found" when I try `/Files/Index/some/path/here`

Comment: Are you using route attributes or the MVC4 technique?

Comment: Did you register the MVC5 routes?

Comment: Excellent, it works for routes. Any idea how to allow file extensions? `/Files/test/path/` works but `/Files/test/path/somefile.pdf` does not.

Comment: I noticed that it works fine for long paths, but for short paths like `Files/p/test.pdf`, it is 404.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way would be to use a query string like

```
http://www.website.com/Home/Index?route=%2fFiles%2fsome%2fpath%2fhere
```

or as a parameter in an action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go To Index", "Index", "Home", new {route= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(/Files/some/path/here)}, null)
```

Make sure you escape `/` characters like above

Answer (score 1):

You have to do more than just define the route.

In RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "FilePathRoute",
        url: "FilePath/Index/{*filePath}",
        defaults: new{ controller="FilePath", action="Index"});
```

Also, you have to tell the web server not to intercept URLs that look like static files. For instance, in IIS Express, clear the `preCondition` attribute:

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule"
     preCondition="" />
```

With that, the route works:

#### FilePathController.cs:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FilePathInUrl.Controllers
{
    public class FilePathController : Controller
    {
        // GET: FilePath
        public ActionResult Index(string filePath = "")
        {
            ViewBag.FilePath = filePath;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Views/FilePath/Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
    @ViewBag.Filepath
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to ["Pro ASP.NET MVC 4, Fourth Edition"](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/microsoft-aspdotnet/9781430242369) by Adam Freeman, ISBN 1-4302-4236-1; Chapter 13, "URL Routing", heading "Routing Requests for Disk Files". It took about 15 minutes to construct this answer using that book.